# iOS and Xcode : How to set the code signing for deployment?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am about to submit my iOS app on iTunes connect but after hearing about multiple rejections from Apple I want to make things properly. 
The only thing I am not sure about is the Code Signing part in the Build Settings of the target.

Up until now I had left the default configuration but I changed the provisioning profile to my distribution provisioning profile (that is, the provisioning profile which has the production certificate) because it seems kind of logical. But I am now wondering if I should have left the default settings. Could you tell me if what I've done is correct?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an archive to submit to the store, the app will be built using the **Release** configuration (Top left of xCode, click on the *Scheme* dropdown (next to the **stop** button) and you choose *edit scheme* to see how an archive uses *release*)

So in **Build Settings/Code Signing** you will see that you can specify a different profile for *Debug* and *Release* under **Code Signing Entitlements**.

For debug, this to your *Developer Profile*, for release set this to the *Distribution Profile*.

If you are building the app for a development built it will use the developer profile while an archive for the store will sign with the distribution - and you won't need to keep switching back and forth.